# Misunderstanding how end= argument works in print() function in a while loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, file

Hi so I just started learning how to read files in Python. So, I started writing a file using Python using the code:

```
with open('dog_breeds.txt', 'w') as writer:
    writer.write("Pug\r\nJack Russell Terrier\r\nEnglish Springer Spaniel\r\nGerman Shepherd\r\nStaffordshire Bull Terrier\r\nCavalier King Charles Spaniel\r\nGolden Retriever\r\nWest Highland White Terrier\r\nBoxer\r\nBorder Terrier\r\n")
    writer.close()
```

This results in a .txt file which image can be seen [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3RvmY.png).

Then, I start to run the following code:

```
import time
reader = open('dog_breeds.txt', 'r+')
line = reader.readline()
print('Output of readline while loop is: ')
while line != '':
    print(line, end='')
    time.sleep(1)
    line = reader.readline()
reader.close()
```

Then, I got this output when I execute the code:

```
Output of readline while loop is:
Pug

Jack Russell Terrier

English Springer Spaniel

German Shepherd

Staffordshire Bull Terrier

Cavalier King Charles Spaniel

Golden Retriever

West Highland White Terrier

Boxer

Border Terrier
```

So, I am a little confused. I thought that the `end = ''` argument in the print() will cause each line in the .txt file to be printed at the end of the previous line that is printed, resulting in one long line being displayed (i.e. PugJackRussellTerrierEnglish...). Instead, what is displayed is multiple lines with each line in the .txt file being a separate line. Is there something I am misunderstanding?

Comment: Lines already contain a \n in them. Use rstrip to fix that.

Comment: When using a context manager to open your files, you do not need to close them. They will be closed automatically.

Comment: Also, you don't have to do `line = reader.readline()`, you can just iterate the lines directly: for line in reader: ...`

Comment: The code shown will not produce that output - i.e., with blank lines interspersing the dog breed names

Answer (score 0):

This written script can execute as you want:

```
import time
reader = open('dog_breeds.txt', 'r+')
print('Output of readline while loop is: ')
for i in reader:
    line = i.rstrip("\n")
    if line:
        print(line)
        time.sleep(1)
reader.close()
```

pay attention to the `.replace("\n", "")`.

The result of running the above code is the following output:

```
Output of readline while loop is: 
Jack Russell Terrier
English Springer Spaniel
German Shepherd
Staffordshire Bull Terrier
Cavalier King Charles Spaniel
Golden Retriever
West Highland White Terrier
Boxer
Border Terrier
```

And each line will be printed after one second as you intended in your code.

Comment: 1) There's no need to use `.readlines()`; file objects are already iterables of their lines and unlike calling `.readlines()`, it operates lazily, so you don't have to pull the whole file into memory before you can process a single line; `for line in reader:` works fine. 2) `i.replace("\n", "")` involves scanning the whole string when it definitionally ends in at most one newline. `line = line.rstrip("\n")` avoids the cost of scanning the whole string; we know it's only at the end, if at all. 3) If you're switching to the `for` loop, you want to remove the initial `line = reader.readline()`.

Comment: @ShadowRanger tnx a lot. I modified the code above as per your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

By default python uses a new line in print.(print has `end="\n"` as default value)

your file uses `\r\n` for each line so if you try to print it line by line in a loop with normal print (without `end=""`)

it would print something like this format:

```
*first_line_in_file
*new empty line because you have \r\n
*new empty line because python print(end="\n")
*second line
...
```

but now with end=""
it's like this:

```
*first_line_in_file
*new empty line because you have \r\n
*second line
...
```

**Conclusion**:
`end=""` doesn't remove `\n` from your text it just stops python from adding extra `\n` to your output.

Comment: Hi I tried my code without the `end=''` but now there are three empty lines between each dog name. With the `end=''`, there is still just one empty line between each dog name.

Comment: Additionally, doesn't any string that comes after a `\n` in Python get printed immediately from the start of the next line? (e.g. `print(Hello\nWorld)`) will give: 
```first line Hello 
second line World```

instead of:
```first line Hello
second line empty
third line World``` ?

Because your explanation pseudocode seems to say that the latter will happen.

Comment: I think the issue is with \r\n. it can be written to file as 2 new lines. so it can be `*first_line_in_file` `*new empty line because you have \r` `new empty line because you have \n` *new empty line because python print(end="\n")  so using `end=''` removes the third new line.

Comment: my pseudocode is about using multiple prints or print in a loop. so `print(Hello\nWorld)` will give: `first line Hello` `second line World` but same print in a loop will give you `first line Hello` `second line World` `third line Hello` `forth line World` but with `end=""` in a loop will give you `first line Hello` `second line WorldHello` `third line World`.

Comment: file.write will return how many characters are written to file. check it out. it should give you a perspective of how `\r\n` are handled in your file and also when you read a line you can use `repr(line_variable)` to see how many `\n` exists in your text and how many python adds as part of print.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you are using Windows, but when I ran your code:

```
with open('dog_breeds.txt', 'w') as writer:
    writer.write("Pug\r\nJack Russell Terrier\r\nEnglish Springer Spaniel\r\nGerman Shepherd\r\nStaffordshire Bull Terrier\r\nCavalier King Charles Spaniel\r\nGolden Retriever\r\nWest Highland White Terrier\r\nBoxer\r\nBorder Terrier\r\n")
```

On my Windows machine, the line break `\r\n` creates two line breaks:

```
Pug

Jack Russell Terrier

English Springer Spaniel

German Shepherd

Staffordshire Bull Terrier

Cavalier King Charles Spaniel

Golden Retriever

West Highland White Terrier

Boxer

Border Terrier
```

So when you start reading the file, even though you print using the `end=''` parameter, there will still be an extra new line.

To overcome this, you need to check if the line has data while stripping it and then print it, if the line has data, example:

```
with open('dog_breeds.txt') as reader:
    for line in reader:
        if line.rstrip(): # if the stripped line has data
            print(line.rstrip(), end='')
```

Result:

```
PugJack Russell TerrierEnglish Springer SpanielGerman ShepherdStaffordshire Bull TerrierCavalier King Charles SpanielGolden RetrieverWest Highland White TerrierBoxerBorder Terrier
```

Comment: Yes I am using Windows Command Prompt to run the code but I still get the text as shown in the image I posted in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Here's something that will work on both Unix and Windows systems:

```
import re

FILE = 'dog_breeds.txt'

with open(FILE, 'w') as writer:
    writer.write("Pug\r\nJack Russell Terrier\r\nEnglish Springer Spaniel\r\nGerman Shepherd\r\nStaffordshire Bull Terrier\r\nCavalier King Charles Spaniel\r\nGolden Retriever\r\nWest Highland White Terrier\r\nBoxer\r\nBorder Terrier\r\n")

with open(FILE) as reader:
    print(re.sub('[\r\n]', '', reader.read()))
```

**Output:**

```
PugJack Russell TerrierEnglish Springer SpanielGerman ShepherdStaffordshire Bull TerrierCavalier King Charles SpanielGolden RetrieverWest Highland White TerrierBoxerBorder Terrier
```

Answer (score -2):

https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print

"Both sep and end must be strings; they can also be None, which means to use the default values. If no objects are given, print() will just write end."